# chrome extension - how to use getCurrentTab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use getCurrentTab from [chrome developer site](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab),
but, I get an error in line:`let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);`

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback): No matching signature.

```
// backround.js

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo) {
   tab=getCurrentTab();
   alert(tab.url)
 });

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: 1) You probably aren't using ManifestV3, 2) tab=getCurrentTab() should be tab = await getCurrentTab() and the containing function should be declared as `async`, look for more info in a tutorial on async/await.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, v2 was the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm  How can I use alert instead of console.log?